# Языковые переменные Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как в шаблоне wordpress правильно использовать текст, который не задаётся из админки, для дальнейшего перевода на мультиязычном сайте, например где-то нужно вывести просто слово.

Answer (score 1):

Это не хорошая практика. Для таких вещей в крайнем случае лучше создать отдельный файл с переводами завязанными на какие-то ключи...

Comment: Я догадываюсь, что писать текст в шаблоне не очень, но как быть? В шаблоне есть текст вспомогательный, который нет смысла выводить через виджет из-за количества этого текста по сайту. А сайт ещё нужно выполнить на 3-х языках. Как лучше поступить тут?

Comment: вы используете какой-то плагин для мультииязычки? может есть какая-то глабальная переменная с признаком какой язык? и в зависимости от него эхать определенные строки. Но я не считаю что и это хороший вариант...

Comment: Ещё не использую, буду только подходить в вопросу, вот хочу понять как лучше сразу делать. А плагин для перевода контента буду использовать qTranslate.

Comment: Не использовал. Ничего сказать не могу. Полиленг неплохой плагин.

Comment: Только qtranslateX используйте, потому что qtranslate давным давно не поддерживается